# Php Array multidimensional associative compare value

Tags: php, foreach

Hi I have such a structure array. I would like compare in loop  such  a condition.

```
if(dataInto[0]>=MyDataTypeFromInput && dataOut[0]<=MyDataTypeFromInput && room[0]==MyIdRoom) {...}
```

instead index 0, this have to  work in loop foreach. So compare  index [0] with index[0] [1] with [1] etc

How do this?

```
[
'dataInto' => [
    0 => '2016-07-14 14:50'
    1 => '2016-03-24 14:00'
    2 => '2016-03-03 06:30'
]
'room' => [
    0 => 13
    1 => 14
    2 => 14
]
'dataOut' => [
    0 => '2016-07-14 18:10'
    1 => '2016-03-24 17:20'
    2 => '2016-03-03 09:50'
   ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply perform a `foreach` loop based on the length of one of main array items:

```
foreach( $array['dataInto'] as $key => $val )
{
    if
    (
        $array['dataInto'][$key] >= MyDataTypeFromInput 
        && 
        $array['dataOut'][$key]  <= MyDataTypeFromInput 
        && 
        $array['room'][$key]     == MyIdRoom
    )
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this in a foreach loop, a more sensible approach would be using a for loop since all indexes are numeric.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($arr['dataInto']); $i++){
  if($arr['dataInto'][$i] >= MyDataTypeFromInput
  && $arr['dataOut'][$i]  <= MyDataTypeFromInput
  && $arr['room'][$i]     == MyIdRoom){
    // etc..
  }
}
```

If however you want to loop the main array a foreach loop is in order.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){ 
  echo $key, ', '; // ouput: "dataInto, dataOut, room" 
  foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue){
    echo $subkey, ' -> ', $subvalue; // will first loop dataInto and display all 3 values with numeric keys 0, 1, 2.
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand your second code, but I need searching value after string index. Is there any other way yet to make it work? I would like see other solution ;)